# How to configure Emacs to use variable fonts to display the previsualisation of LaTeX formulas?

Tags: emacs, fonts, latex, org-mode

I would like to use Emacs 24.2.1 in orgmode 7.9.3 on a data projector in class.

- I can pre-visualize latex formulas using org-preview-latex-fragment (C-c C-x C-l), and
- I can increase the font used to display the text using text-scale-increase (C-+).

The problem is that the math fonts are not increasing along the text fonts.

Is there a way to configure Emacs so that the math fonts are variable too?
Was this solved in a later version of orgmode (I was planning to wait for the end of the term to upgrade to version 8+, being afraid of having to invest a lot of time in updating my configuration).

Answer (score 4):

A poor man's solution that works with advices and hooks is shown below.
Paste the code into your .emacs configuration file and re-start emacs. Afterwards, the equation images should be scaled <del>at</del> *along with the text if you press* C-+/-/0. *They are just previews and their* <del>The bad thing is that the</del> resolution is not enlarged. To get equation images with a good resolution hit C-c C-x C-l to regenerate the images. *Note, that this sets the :scale property of the customization variable org-format-latex-options. The customization of this variable will be lost for the current emacs session.*

You need a gnu-emacs with built-in imagemagick. Should be standard by now.

```
(defvar text-scale-mode-hook nil
"Hook run at end of command `text-scale-mode'.")

(defadvice text-scale-mode (after text-scale-mode-hooks nil activate)
  "Run `text-scale-mode-hook' at end of command `text-scale-mode'."
  (if (functionp text-scale-mode-hook)
      (funcall text-scale-mode-hook)
    (loop for hook in text-scale-mode-hook do
      (if (eq hook 't)
          (run-hooks (default-value text-scale-mode-hook))
        (run-hooks hook)))))

(defun org-text-scale-eye ()
  "Scale equation images according to text-scale-mode-amount."
  (when (boundp 'text-scale-mode-amount)
    (let ((relwidth (* (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount))))
    (loop for ol in (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max)) do
      (when (eq (overlay-get ol 'org-overlay-type) 'org-latex-overlay)
        (unless (overlay-get ol 'org-image-original-width)
          (overlay-put ol 'org-image-original-width (car (image-size (overlay-get ol 'display) t))))
        (let ((ol-disp-plist (cdr (overlay-get ol 'display))))
          (setq ol-disp-plist (plist-put ol-disp-plist :type 'imagemagick))
          (setq ol-disp-plist (plist-put ol-disp-plist :width (round (* relwidth (overlay-get ol 'org-image-original-width)))))
          (overlay-put ol 'display (append '(image) ol-disp-plist))
          ))))
    (force-window-update)
    ))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda () (add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'org-text-scale-eye)))

(defadvice org-format-latex (before set-scale activate)
  "Set :scale in `org-format-latex-options' to the scaling factor resulting from `text-scale-mode' and clear cache."
  (let ((relwidth (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount)))
    (unless (= (plist-get org-format-latex-options :scale) relwidth)
      (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale relwidth))))
```

Actually, I had a look at the code in org.el:
The font height is regarded in the function org-create-formula-image-with-dvipng and the resolution option -D is set. Maybe, there goes something wrong. Furthermore, pityingly, in org-format-latex the images are cached and not reproduced after font size changes.

If you want to increase the size of the latex-formulas for one session in general with good quality you can set the :scale value of the customization option "Org Format Latex Options" in the group "org-latex" to a higher value.

*Edit 2013-10-10 (marked as italic throughout the answer except the code, naturally): The :scale property of the option org-format-latex-options is now set automagically. Therefore, the above hack should be quite usable (such as the latex version mentioned below).*

---

The same problem as you describe in the original-post exists for latex-preview. But, for that case there is a better solution:

```
(require 'face-remap)
(defadvice preview-inherited-face-attribute (after preview-inherit-local-face nil activate)
  "Scale preview images with respect to buffer-local face"
  (when (and text-scale-mode (eq attribute :height))
    (setq ad-return-value (* (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount) ad-return-value))))
```

After C-+/-/0 type C-c C-p C-d to re-generate all formulas of the document. Afterwards, the formulas have just the right size and the right resolution.

If switching to latex documents with preview is an option for you I would recommend it. I use org only for notes and time-tables with easy links.

For more descriptive documents I use latex documents with auctex/preview. But, I actually compile them only very seldom to a final pdf document. The preview is good enough. See the following Figure.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer! I want to use orgmode as opposed to pdf, so that I can mark as done items in check boxes, and roll/unroll entries as I go. What version of Emacs/Orgmode do you use?

Comment: Okay, then you should try the first code-box with the application hints above it.

Comment: org-ersion: 8.0.5. Do you encounter problems with 7.9.3? If so, what problems?